# Why can't a user with read and execute permissions cd to a directory through a symlink?

Tags: nginx, permissions, symlink, cd

I have hit upon an interesting behaviour relating to symlinks and `cd`.

I have a user `www`, in the group `totalolage`

[image]

I have a symbolically linked directory `/tmp/www/`->`/home/totalolage/Projects/.../public`

[image]

The target directory (`public`) and all containing directories are accessible and `cd`-to-able by the user `www`. However when I attempt to access the `public` directory with the user `www` through the symlink, I am denied permission.

[image]

This does not happen for the user `totalolage`.

[image]

I would love to know why this happens and how I can circumvent it?

I am trying to use `/tmp/www/` as a changeable root for a local `nginx` server, so when I want to debug something I can just link it to the directory without fiddling about with config files or ports. The `nginx` server is running as the user `www` though and so `php-fpm` cannot read `/tmp/www/index.php`.

Comment: In Apache, I would have to add the option to follow SymLinks.  I do not know if there is an equivalent for nginx.

Comment: @Nic3500 yes that is an option I have set, but this behaviour is independant of the whole server stich. `cd` itself **should** work regardless of any config files.